# Is it normal to wait 50 min for baking a "simple" fluid animation?

Tags: baking, fluid-simulation

[image]

As said in the title, is it normal for this to take so long? In this video it takes them seconds to bake (video: https://youtu.be/xIxUZpRk4Ac?t=147), they stated that they had a GTX970 but I don't think GPUs affect bake time.

Also while I'm writing this, it says elapsed time is 20 min and time remaining 30 min.

Here are my specs:

- CPU

  - Intel Core i7 6700K @ 4.00GHz
  - Skylake 14nm Technology
- RAM

  - 16,0GB Single-Channel Unknown @ 1069MHz (15-15-15-36)
- Motherboard
- ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. STRIX Z270F GAMING (LGA1151)
- Graphics

  - ROG PG278QR (2560x1440@144Hz)
  - 4095MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 (Gigabyte)
- Storage
- 931GB Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB (SATA (SSD)
- 465GB Samsung SSD 840 EVO 500GB (SATA (SSD))

Comment: The elapsed time just went up :( from 30 to 40 min I am probably doing something wrong that causes blender not to bake this properly

Comment: This may or may not be normal. Blenders fluid sim is not really optimized and is very slow. You can try to set the resolutions much lower for a preview while youÄre testing parameters and changing them. Right now, you're baking at 200 (and only seeing 100 in the viewport), which is probably not necessary to evaluate the motion. Set **both** values to 60~90 for a speedup. The resolution is not directly proportional to the baking time so even 100/100 will be faster than half the time. For the final bake for a 10s a few days should be considered.

Comment: Few days for final bake of this..pls no. Just download the free version of Houdini, do any simulation there accelerated with OpenCL on gpu and export the final mesh/meshes as obj/objs. Render it in Cycles. And forget about simulating anything in Blender until the whole system gets refresh.

Comment: I use a i5 CPU, and when I bake 200 frames @280 resolution it usually takes 3 to 4 hours. So I'd say "days" are not necessarily the case for a i7 user. Blender fluid simulator can still be used for simple simulations.. however, by version 2.81/2.82 a completely new one is expected (check out the mantaflow project)

Comment: I did the same simulation and its only at 8% when its been 30 minutes or so. im on a school laptop lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems quite normal - fluid simulations are very CPU intensive to bake and the workload increases exponentially based on the simulation Resolution (eg, doubling the Resolution results in 8 times the number of 'cells' in the domain (2x2x2)).

If you look closely at the video, shortly after the guy hits 'Bake', the mouse jumps to slightly above the bake button. Most likely he paused the video midway, allowed it to complete the bake, then carried on as if it had only taken seconds - whereas, really, it likely took a similar amount of time as you are experiencing.